# Выполнить функцию вписанную в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, смотрите, я имею инпут в который я вписываю `Math.sqrt(19)/15` втором нажимаю на кнопку, и мне надо чтобы значение этого выражение мне выдало соседний `input`.
Как забирать и вставлять значение из инпутов я знаю, но мне надо узнать как выполнить эту функцию или выражение вписанное в инпут.
Поможете? А то я даже не знаю как мне в Гугл вбить...
Используйте jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval()`

[Запуск кода из строки: eval](http://learn.javascript.ru/eval)

Answer (score 1):

Функция eval() - "выполняет строку".

```
$('input[name=result]').val(eval($('input[name=hz_func]').val()));
```