# Перевод строки в код

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, строки

У меня есть переменная `y = "x*x"`, что нужно сделать чтобы превратить это в исполняемый код. То есть при вызове `f(y)` мне вместо `f("x*x")` подставлялось `f(x*x)`

Comment: По какому закону из `"xx"` должно получиться `x*x`? Какая нотация используется в `"xx"`?

Comment: @Dmitry, по закону «символ `*` используется в markdown разметке для выделения курсивом» :)

Comment: @diraria забавно, не разгадал я эту загадку с курсивом

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнить функцию вписанную в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242191/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-input)

Comment: @Yuri я бы все-таки не стал объявлять вопрос дубликатом (по крайней мере, в эту сторону). В том вопросе слишком много деталей (input какой-то взялся, хотя на решение источник строки не влияет).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, однако задача аналогичная. +Я поставил минус за лень. Я написал в поиске "js выполнение кода из строки" и мне кучу сайтов выдало :)

Comment: @Yuri *ну, теперь и этот сайт в том списке появится*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
f(eval(y));
```

Живой пример:

```js
function f(number) {
  console.log(number);
}

let x = 7;
let y = "x*x";
f(eval(y));
```

[Однако не стоит использовать `eval` без лишней необходимости, возможно стоит переписать код по другому.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it)

Answer (score 3):

Именно в таком виде вам подойдет ругаемый многими [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (но только в том случае, когда вычисляемое вами выражение получено из **доверенного** источника!):

```
var x = 5;
var expr = "x*x";
console.log(eval(expr)); // 25
```

Но это - довольно опасная функция, поскольку она имеет доступ ко всем вашим локальным переменным и может, к примеру, перезаписать любую из них. Если не допускать ошибок, то это не страшно - но ошибки делают все. Поэтому можно воспользоваться одной из более ограниченных функций.

Второй вариант - [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), позволяет дать доступ только к глобальным переменным и явно указанному списку параметров, что защитит от сюрпризов, вызванных конфликтами имен:

```
var expr = "x*x";
var exprF = new Function("x", "return " + expr);
console.log(exprF(5)); // 25
```

Для того, чтобы "спрятать" глобальные переменные от *случайного* обращения к ним, можно использовать трюк со скрытым фреймом:

```
<iframe id="jscontext" href="about:blank" style="display:none"></iframe>

var jscontext = document.getElementById('jscontext').contentWindow;
var expr = "x*x";
var exprF = new jscontext.Function("x", "return " + expr);
console.log(exprF(5)); // 25
```

Тем не менее, этот трюк не защищает вас ни от намеренного обращения к вашим глобальным переменным, ни от взаимодействия с вашими серверами от имени текущего пользователя (это называется XSS-атакой). Поэтому, если строка была получена из недоверенного источника - к ней нельзя применять ни один из этих методов.

Выходом в таком случае будет создание своего языка выражения как подмножества javascript, с последующим написанием своего парсера для него. Или же можно воспользоваться готовыми парсерами javascript, например [esprima](http://esprima.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = 2,
    y = "x*x";

alert( eval(y) );
```

Но `eval` -  это очень, очень плохо!
<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it</sub>

Comment: eval случайно не от evil?

Comment: @vadimuha, скорее всего `eval` это сокращение от слова `evaluation`